# compile and install qtcurve successfully but system settings can't find it

Tags: linux, kde, compile, source-code

I use kubuntu and I compiled the source of qtcurve and installed (the result is shown at the end).
After, I went to `System Settings -> Application Appearance -> Style -> Applications -> Widget Style`, but there is no `qtcurve` to choose there. If I use `sudo apt-get install qtcurve`, there is `qtcurve` to choose. I guess the problem is that qtcurve is installed to a different location, but I don't know how to fix this problem.

```
[  0%] Built target kstyle_qtcurve_config_automoc
[ 23%] Built target kstyle_qtcurve_config
[ 23%] Built target translations
[ 23%] Built target kwin3_qtcurve_automoc
[ 43%] Built target kwin3_qtcurve
[ 43%] Built target kwin_qtcurve_config_automoc
[ 52%] Built target kwin_qtcurve_config
[100%] Built target qtcurve
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/kde4/kstyle_qtcurve_config.so
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib/kde4/kstyle_qtcurve_config.so" to "/usr/local/lib"
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/QtCurveui.rc
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/Agua.qtcurve
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/Agua_II.qtcurve
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/Curve.qtcurve
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/Flat.qtcurve
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/Human.qtcurve
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/Inverted.qtcurve
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/Klearlooks.qtcurve
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/Milk.qtcurve
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/Murrine.qtcurve
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/Ozone.qtcurve
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/Plastic.qtcurve
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/QtCurve/Silk.qtcurve
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/color-schemes/QtCurve.colors
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/color-schemes/QtCurveAgua.colors
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/qtcurve.mo
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/qtcurve.mo
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/qtcurve.mo
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/qtcurve.mo
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/qtcurve.mo
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/qtcurve.mo
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/qtcurve.mo
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/kde4/kwin3_qtcurve.so
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib/kde4/kwin3_qtcurve.so" to "/usr/local/lib"
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/kwin/qtcurve.desktop
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/kde4/kwin_qtcurve_config.so
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib/kde4/kwin_qtcurve_config.so" to "/usr/local/lib"
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/apps/kstyle/themes/qtcurve.themerc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/kde4/plugins/styles/qtcurve.so
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/lib/kde4/plugins/styles/qtcurve.so" to "/usr/local/lib"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something is wrong with prefix path - must be /usr, not /usr/local (which is default).

As I see, your sources using cmake program to compile, so don't forget to add

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr
```

when running cmake.